# Infinite sets of rvs equal in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Assume $\{\mathcal{L}(X_{k})\}_{k\in I}=\{\mathcal{L}(Y_{k})\}_{k\in I}$ for all finite $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ i.e. equal in all finite dimensional distributions. Then I want to show that $\mathbb{P}(sup_{k>N}X_{k}>x)=\mathbb{P}(sup_{k>N}Y_{k}>x)$.

**Attempt**

1)$A_{M}=\bigcap_{M>k>N}\{X_{k}<x\}\supset A_{M+1}$. So by continuity of measure $P(\bigcap_{k>N}\{X_{k}<x\})=lim_{M\to \infty}P(\bigcap_{M>k>N}\{X_{k}<x\})=lim_{M\to \infty}P(\bigcap_{M>k>N}\{Y_{k}<x\})=P(\bigcap_{k>N}\{Y_{k}<x\})$. Then take complements to get answer.

In case, I made a mistake here is an alternative approach.

2)We have $\{sup_{k>N}X_{k}<x\}=\bigcap_{k>N}\{X_{k}<x\}$. By Kolmogorov's extension theorem, there exists unique extension $P_{*}$ of measures $P_{I}(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i})=P(\bigcap_{i\in I}X_{i}\in A_{i})$ (these are consistent because $P(X\in \mathbb{R})=1$. Thus, by uniqueness $P_{*}(\{sup_{M>k>N}X_{k}<x\})=P_{*}(\bigcap_{M>k>N}\{X_{k}<x\})=P_{*}(\bigcap_{M>k>N}\{Y_{k}<x\})=P_{*}(\{sup_{M>k>N}Y_{k}<x\})$.

Now I would like to take $M\to \infty$ however $\bigcap_{k>N}\{X_{k}<x\}$ is not a cylinder event.

Comment: Why not simply use that the event $\left\{\sup\limits_{k\geqslant N}X_k>x\right\}$ is the nondecreasing union over $n$ of the events $\left\{\max\limits_{N\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k>x\right\}=\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^N\{X_k>x\}$, and likewise for $(Y_k)$?